# How to implement a instance of Functor for a self defined data in haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm a beginner of Haskell. Now I tried to define a data as following:

```
data Unsure a = Sure a |Error [Char]
 deriving (Show)
```

then tried to implement Functor like this:

```
instance Functor Unsure where
    fmap f (Sure x) = Sure (f x)
    fmap f (Error e) = Error e
```

In my opinion, fmap should work Once I implemented Functor for Unsure. So I can use fmap to do something like:

```
fmap (+3) (+100) Sure 1
```

The result was supposed to be **Sure 104** , in fact I got a error

> • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (Unsure a)
>         (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
>       • When checking the inferred type
>           it :: forall a. (Num (Unsure a), Num a) => Unsure a

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you think that should work?

Comment: I got a mistake, now when I'm typing fmap (+3) Sure 1, it shows Sure 4.

Comment: Actually I want a general way to unbox Unsure then I can do something such as fmap (==)  100 (Sure 100).

Comment: This is an interesting error! If you had written `fmap (+3) (Sure 1)` things would have worked, as would have `fmap (+3) (+100) 1` (for subtle reasons). If you had written `fmap (+3) Sure 1` you might have gotten a reasonable error message, but `fmap (+3) (+100) Sure 1` is a perfect storm that creates a nasty error message.

Comment: You can already do this, you just need to bring the `100` inside the parentheses: `fmap (==100) (Sure 100)` <-- returns `Sure True`.

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 3):

You probably intended to write `fmap ((+3) . (+100)) (Sure 1)` or `fmap (+3) $ fmap (+100) (Sure 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

*fmap* is a function that has the type `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

In words, the function *fmap* takes **two** arguments: 
The first argument is a function of from a type `a` to `b`.
The second argument is a value of a Functor of type `a`. The result is a Functor of type `b`.

In your example you write: `fmap (+3) (+100) Sure 1`. In this example *fmap* has **four** arguments:
First is `(+3)` , second is `(+100)`, third id `Sure` and fourth is `1`.

As written  by @Brian Olivier to make one argument out of `(+3)` and `(+100)`
you can combine them with the (.) operator and put this expression into parenthesis. This then gives you the first argument of fmap.

Then you have to put `Sure 1` into parenthesis 
to get the second argument of fmap.

So all together you have to write `fmap ((+3) . (+100)) (Sure 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, if you add use the `DeriveFunctor` language extensions (eg via the `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}` pragma) you can just derive functor:

```
data Unsure a = Sure a |Error [Char]
  deriving (Show, Functor)
```